# Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching

Tags: spring-boot

I have requirement where I need to migrate from Spring to `SpringBoot` application. Currently having `SOAP` service which internally connecting to https `REST` api that included in `application.properties` file. I am using command clean package spring-boot:run which build application successfully.

But when try to call `SOAP` services, getting error Caused by:

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS
>   name matching momgodbservice.nam.nsroot.net found.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using ? The reason this error in java 1.8.0_181 is because this update includes security improvements for LDAP support. “Endpoint identification” has been enabled on LDAPS connections.
According to JDK 8u181 Update Release Notes, endpoint identification algorithms have been enabled by default to improve the robustness of LDAPS (secure LDAP over TLS) connections.
This update applies to all of the following Java versions and their future releases.

Comment: I am using jdk1.8.0_211

Answer (score 0):

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS
>   name matching  found

Cause:

There can be multiple causes to this issue.

Application may check the hostname on SSL certificates when communicating with an LDAP server over SSL. What this means is that the hostname used to connect to the LDAP server must match that of the SSL certificate, or application will not be able to connect to the directory.

The exception is thrown when you are trying to make a secure connection over SSL and the hostname you are trying to connect is not valid when compared to the SSL certificate of the server.

Comment: Could we disable CN name varification from any property?

Comment: I have one more query I am having spring REST client in child project which is build using jdk1.7 and while migrtaing to SpringBott is there any way without touching child rest client in spring boot we could set ssl certificate for child project rest client.

Comment: this doesn't really address the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as OP.  For me there was no LDAP server anywhere in the architecture.

I had a wildcard SSL cert on the AWS load balancer: *.mydomain.com.  I added the specific domain names that the application was using to the same SSL cert so it had three entries: *.mydomain.com, qa.api.myapp.mydomain.com and api.myapp.mydomain.com.  Once this cert was on the load balancer where SSL was terminated, the java application worked flawlessly (at least from an SSL perspective)
Timothy